# Use FeedMe with a dynamic URL

Tags: json, plugin-feedme

The list of entries I need to grab is available here:

```
http://arcresources.mediaroom.com/api/newsfeed_releases/list.php?format=json
```

Each *individual* entry is available at a unique URL, by adding an ID, like so:

```
http://arcresources.mediaroom.com/api/newsfeed_releases/get.php?format=json?id=n
```

Is there some way to get FeedMe to create entries for every ID from the list URL, using the get URL?

Comment: I've never used FeedMe so I can't answer your question unfortunately; but I just wanted to say nice website!

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way to achieve this with Feed Me. A single feed would represent a collection of items to be imported as elements/entries.

One method your could consider is setting up a feed for a single entry, then use the optional `url` parameter when calling it via the direct feed URL. This overrides the URL used in your feed settings with the one you provide.

This is described https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me/docs/feature-tour/trigger-import-via-cron